# How to rewrite paged URL's?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have changed my web page url from `localhost/products.php` to `localhost/products` using the code below.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /products\.php[\s/?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /products [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^products/?$ products.php [L,NC]
```

But when I navigate to next page, address bar shows something like:
`localhost/products?page=2` which I want to appear as `localhost/products/page2`

Tried this `RewriteRule ^products/page/([0-9]+)/?$ products.php?page=$1 [L]` but this did not work.
My full code for rewriting page url is:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /products\.php[\s/?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /products [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^products/?$ products.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^products/page/([0-9]+)/?$ products.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Here how can I change the URL for next pages? I mean from `localhost/products?page=2` to `localhost/products/page2` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following rule :

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /products/?(?:\.php)?\?page=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /products/%1? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^products/([0-9]+)/?$ /products.php?page=$1 [L,NC]
```

This will convert the urls

- /products.php?page=number
- /products/?page=number

to

- /products/number

Comment: error when navigating to another page, firefox error **The page isn't redirecting properly**,  chrome error **localhost redirected you too many times.**